# Bootstrap: <a> removes left and right margin from span

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm pretty new to Twitter Bootstrap and I have a problem that I would suspect is pretty easy to overcome, if you know where to look ;o)

I have wrapped 3 `<span4>` in `<a>`. This removes the margin/gutter between the `<span4>` which is not what I want. I have tried to add the margin by:

```
a > .span4 { margin: 0 1.7% };
```

However, this solution does not work entirely as intended when you resize the browser. Does anyone have a suggestion to how I can fix this?

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">    
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span8 offset2">     
            <a href="#"><div class="span4">
                <h2>Box 1</h2>
                <p>Text here</p>
            </div></a>
            <a href="#"><div class="span4">
                <h2>Box 2</h2>
                <p>Text here</p>
            </div></a>
            <a href="#"><div class="span4">
                <h2>Box 3</h2>
                <p>Text here</p>
            </div></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It looks like this (just added a white background-color for test):

[image]

I would like to have a responsive margin between the `<span4>` divs like they have without the `<a>` wrapping.

I hope you will be able to help me. Thanks.

Kind regards
- Jesper

Comment: you do realize that your inner span's sum up to 12 - but you only have a wrapping div with span8 wide?

Comment: You neglected to create a new row for your nested spans (which is why the margin is missing).  See my answer below

Comment: @MichaelRose That's how the responsive bootstrap grid system works.  He just needs to nest his sum of 12 within a new `row-fluid` div

Comment: Can you place your anchor tag inside div??

Answer (score 1):

In order to nest spans, you need to create a new `row-fluid` div.

**Edit:** you'll also want your links *inside* your span divs (which works fine if you make them `display:block;`)

[Here's some jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X6YYp/1/)

```
<div class="container-fluid">    
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span8 offset2"> 
            <div class="row-fluid">    <!-- make sure to add this div-->
                <div class="span4">
                    <a href="#">
                        <h2>Box 1</h2>
                        <p>Text here</p>
                    </a>
                </div>
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<style type="text/css">
    a,a:link {
        display:block;
        background-color:#fff;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

default display of `a` tag is display:inline;

you just try to add display:block for that a tag

```
a{display:block}
```

then you try with this

```
a > .span4 { margin: 0 1.7% };
```

Comment: -1 Tweaking the margin of the `span` classes defeats the whole purpose of using bootstrap and should not be encouraged

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest simply using the `a` as the grid piece rather than the `div` it contains. For instance:

```
<a href="#" class="span4">
  <div>
    <h2>Box 1</h2>
    <p>Text here</p>
  </div>
 </a>
```

And, at this point, you may choose to get rid of the containing `div` altogether.

Why do this? Well, it gives you the width, padding, and margin that you want without needing to write more code. And it's no less semantic than using the `div` as the grid piece.

The Bootstrap grid system is pretty complete, and Ponraj's solution is writing more code to do something that's already there. You should probably only extend the grid system if you're trying to add more functionality to it.